# Question about PowerBuilder .net application

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a question about migration of PowerBuilder application to PowerBuilder .net application. When an application is converted to asp.net, does it just create some kind of interface for the web and still uses the PowerBuilder application at backend? or does it creates totally independent application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, there's definitely some confusion. As of the moment (PB 12.0), there is no web deployment from what is known as PowerBuilder.NET. There is a WebForms deployment from PowerBuilder Classic, and it does not involve a migration. Your PB WebForms application will be running PowerBuilder code on the server, which will be generating the UI and other (minimal) front end logic which IIS will send to the browser. A good deal of your code (all your PowerScript) will be run on the server as post-backs, and will be using the PowerBuilder VM (actually, the .NET version of the VM).

Good luck,

Terry.